# Strange errors when trying to implement pffft

Tags: fft

I am trying to create an audio program that can do a variety of spectral processing techniques on an input signal. I am currently stuck on implementing an fft program that runs quickly enough. I tried a recursive and iterative version, neither of which worked quickly enough, so I have begun searching for a reliable and fast fft library I can use instead.

I made a post on KVR and was referred to pffft. I have tried to implement it based on the example from this page: https://github.com/marton78/pffft/blob/master/examples/example_cpp11_cplx_dbl_fwd.cpp
but I am getting these errors when trying to compile.

[image: list of errors]

I copied and pasted the code into my main function to test things out, and I had git cloned the files into the project folder so there should be nothing wrong, but I am still getting these errors on compile. pffft also doesn't have any documentation so I can't use that to get a hint. Any ideas why it might not be working?

Thanks,
Kallyn

Comment: Hi! This is not a signal processing question.
You'll have better luck at https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: One of the most popular libraries for FFT is https://www.fftw.org/. It's highly optimized for a large number of platforms and use cases.